# accessing an SKSpriteNode declared inside a specific method

Tags: swift, timer, skspritenode

In my GameScene class, I have a method called shootLaser that creates an SKSpriteNode called Laser, and adds it as a child of self. This method is called on a timer every several seconds

```
func shootLaser(){
    var Laser = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "LaserDot.png")
    Laser.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
    Laser.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    Laser.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Laser
    Laser.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Blade
    Laser.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Laser.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Laser.physicsBody?.density = 0.5   
    self.addChild(Laser)
}
```

In the update() method, which is automatically called every time a frame is rendered, I try to access the position of the Laser object, but I get an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'Laser'" when I try to set laserLoc to Laser.position

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    // moves every value up an index each frame
    let laserLoc = Laser.position
    if (laserPoints[0] != nil){
        for var index = 9; index >= 1; index--
        {
            laserPoints[index] = laserPoints[index - 1]
        }
        laserPoints[0] = CGPointZero
    }
```

I don't seem to have any issues accessing properties of SKSpriteNodes that are declared in the outside any method. Is there a way around this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I am aware that "Laser" is purely local within the shootLaser() method, but just the same, is there a way I can access its properties in the update method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead putting `Laser` after the class declaration instead of instead of in the function. Like this:

```
class YourClassName: SKScene {

    var Laser = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "LaserDot.png")
```

Also, make sure you remove the declaration of `Laser` inside the function and edit the function to look like this.

```
func shootLaser(){
    var Laser = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "LaserDot.png")
    Laser.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
    Laser.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    Laser.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Laser
    Laser.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Blade
    Laser.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Laser.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Laser.physicsBody?.density = 0.5
    self.Laser.removeFromParent()   
    self.addChild(Laser)
}
```

Comment: This works the first time shootLaser is called, but the second time it is called it tries to add the same SKSpriteNode 'Laser' as a child of self, causing my program to crash